# Weird "infinite update loop" in Vue.js

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have a weird (as I think) problem with Vue. I coded a parent class for handling (sorting, searching and paging) tables. In my subclass, I have the following code, which filters my data on the user's input:

```
// returns filtered data from sorted data [SubClass.vue]
protected get filteredData(): Array<any> {
    return this.sortedData.filter(data => {
        return data[this.searchingKey].toLowerCase().includes(this.searchingTerm.toLowerCase())
    })
}
```

The `sortedData`is a getter of my parent class and just sorts my data array:

```
// returns sorted data from store [ParentClass.vue]
protected get sortedData(): Array<any> {
    const modifier: number = (this.sortingOrder == SortingOrder.Asc) ? 1 : -1

    return this.sourceData.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a[this.sortingKey] < b[this.sortingKey]) return -1 * modifier
        if (a[this.sortingKey] > b[this.sortingKey]) return  1 * modifier
        return 0
    })
}
```

And my data source looks like that:

```
// returns data from store [SubClass.vue]
protected get sourceData(): Array<any> {
    return this.$store.getters.data
}
```

This just works fine. But I need the filtering function to be in my parent class. When I move it, I get this nice little piece of error: `[Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.`

I have no clue why the code works in my subclass but not in the parent...

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example? Maybe in some kind of sandbox?

Comment: I'm not sure because I've never done that and it's complicated with Vue and TypeScript..

Comment: Oh the fun of using Typescript. Hope it's worth it :)

Comment: :D Except of this problem, it is. ^^

Comment: I'm suspicious of `this.sourceData.sort`. It looks like that's sorting the array that's in the store directly, i.e. mutating the original reactive array. That could potentially cause an dependency/update/re-render loop. Try taking a shallow copy of the array before sorting.

Comment: Yes, that was it! Now it's working. Thank you! :) But I still don't know why it is working without copy in the child but not in the parent...